Couldn't redeem TestFlight invitation code - invitation revoked or is invalid
Please help resolve this issue.
Background:

User invited on their personal email to test an iOS app via Apple
Testflight.(personal email is different from Apple Store/ Testflight
email)
User takes the redeem / invitation code and uses it in
another phone belonging to someone else User then asks for another
invitation, to get the app on their own device, but it cannot be
sent, because they have already accepted.
The user is then deleted
and removed from any tester groups within Apple Testflight, and then
re-invited afresh
User cannot use the new testflight redeem/
invitation code . . . Keeps getting error "Couldn't redeem
TestFlight invitation Code ..."...

Please advice how user can get past this issue, or what can I do to give them a working invitation?

I have also faced the same issue. Have you previously accepted the invitation from any other device? I did that and I was only able to redeem the code with the first device I tried.

Hi yes, the invitation was accepted from another device, and token redeemed too. However, the tester has a new device that they need to use, and unfortunately also have a different apple id on the new device. Is there no way to get the invite working again afresh?

Sorry, I am not sure about that but if the new email hasn't been invited then you could send a invite and use it on the new device and it should work.
